# How to change fixed header style according to id of the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make header similar to this site http://www.xapo.com, as you can see from the header it changes background and color when the header goes over other id elements. with javascript or jquery how can i catch the header going over this elements? 
I'm thinking something like getting the outerheight and changing it accordingly. Is there any better solutions?
Thanks in advance

Edit: How I can get it calculate the id element's height and change it automatically? For example in mobile view some section's height could change.

Comment: No it does not, The header is just transparent.

Comment: Heder is transparent first time, but if you scrole down enough header will be white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add and remove a class to the header like this:

Here id="mainContent" is the id of the div where you want to change color. this way you dont have to set it's height every time you reduce or increase height of your slides.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var contentStart = $('#mainContent').offset().top;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($("header").offset().top > contentStart) {
        $("header").addClass("scrolling-nav-header");
    }
    else {
        $("header").removeClass("scrolling-nav-header");
    }
});
});
```

```css
header{
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  paddong:0;
  height:100px;
  background-color:red;
    position:fixed;
}
#firstContent{
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  paddong:100px 0 0 0;
  background-color:green;
}
#mainContent{
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  paddong:0;
  height:300px;
  background-color:black;
}
header.scrolling-nav-header{
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header></header>
<div id="firstContent">
    <p>"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?""
    </p>
</div>
<div id="mainContent"></div>
```

Comment: Instead of looking for `$("header")` and `$('#mainContent').scrollTop()` in each iteration, it will be much better and more efficient to store it in a variable outside of event handler.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get that. which answer?

Comment: Oh my answer already handles the concern you showed in your updated question. that's what `id="maincontent"` is for.

Comment: Thank you :) I will look into it :)

Comment: In my example height of the div above is fixed, so the effect is not visible let me change that, can you please wait five minutes

Comment: @kittyCat thank you, sorry for getting you so late I have a follow up? could you help me?